# How can I print pandas pivot table to word document

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ms-word, pivot-table

Could some one please explain with an example about how we can send the pivot table output from pandas to word document without losing format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596518/writing-a-python-pandas-dataframe-to-word-document?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa, maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

to pip install from the command line:

```
pip install python-docx
```

After that is installed, we can use it to open the file, add a table, and then populate the table's cell text with the data frame data.

```
import docx
import pandas as pd

# i am not sure how you are getting your data, but you said it is a
# pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# open an existing document
doc = docx.Document('./test.docx')

# add a table to the end and create a reference variable
# extra row is so we can add the header row
t = doc.add_table(df.shape[0]+1, df.shape[1])

# add the header rows.
for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
    t.cell(0,j).text = df.columns[j]

# add the rest of the data frame
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
        t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(df.values[i,j])

# save the doc
doc.save('./test.docx')
```

From the answer here at:
[Writing a Python Pandas DataFrame to Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596518/writing-a-python-pandas-dataframe-to-word-document)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest exporting it to csv using `pandas.to_csv()`, and then read the csv to create a table in a word document.

Comment: how to do suggest to "read the `csv` to create a `table` in a word document"?