# How to write multi index pandas DataFrame into docx file

Tags: python, pandas, docx

Normally can do this for dataframes without multi index:

```
import docx

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
doc = docx.Document('./test.docx')

t = doc.add_table(df.shape[0]+1, df.shape[1])

for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
    t.cell(0,j).text = df.columns[j]

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
        t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(df.values[i,j])

doc.save('./test.docx')
```

The problem arises with multi index in DataFrame the output is empty.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532087/how-to-write-groupby-grouped-table-from-dataframe-to-word-document   - Does this help ?

Comment: I dont know how pandas support docx IO with `MultiIndex`, but you still can use `df.reset_index()` before saving your DataFrame, and manually set the `MultiIndex` when reading it.