# Python Script to Export Data from Excel

Tags: python

so I want to write a python script that when executed will automatically pull certain columns from an excel sheet and automatically import them to something like word.

I am familiar with python, just really bad at it and I have a hard time visualizing how to start...

I'm not asking for a full script, just some examples to nudge me in the right direction and some tips going forward with my project.

Thanks for any help you are willing to offer. Have a great day!

Comment: Do you really need to work with Excel files or plain and simple CSV would work as well? Anyway.. check https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Have you checked the pandas library? You can read the excel sheet using it and then filter out your columns in the script itself before importing it to a word document, if that's what you aim to do.

Comment: CSV would work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself familiar with library called `Pandas`. With Pandas you can easily read columns from Excel spreadsheet to a dataframe. You can find Pandas function for that from here: [Python Script to Export Data from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034611/python-script-to-export-data-from-excel) . Also, using `.xlsx` for this purpose is not optimal. You could use, for example,  `.csv` format.

You can write Pandas dataframes to `.docx` file for example this way: [Writing a Python Pandas DataFrame to Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596518/writing-a-python-pandas-dataframe-to-word-document) .