# How to write a xls table to docx using Jupyter python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xls

Hello I am new users of Jupyter python and I have a question:

I have data in xls sheet and I want to write some of the columns in words docx by using python.

I have 12 columns and I want only 3 in docx file.

Comment: How do you want the data in the .docx file to be formatted? For example, one cell per line or 3 columns per line?

Comment: [Writing a Python Pandas DataFrame to Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596518/7758804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, name the range of the 3 columns you're trying to copy in Excel. You can then paste it in your Word document using the following bit:

```
from win32com import client

excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

doc = word.Documents.Open("C:/word_file.docx")
book = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/excel_file.xlsx")

sheet = book.Worksheets(1) #depends on which sheet your named range is located
sheet.Range(NAMED_RANGE_OF_YOUR_TABLE_IN_EXCEL).Copy() 
  
target = doc.Range()
findtext = "WHERE_I_WANT_TO_PASTE_MY_TABLE_IN_WORD" #use a placeholder in your word document where you want the table to appear

if target.Find.Execute(FindText=findtext):
   table_range = doc.Range(Start = target.start, End=target.end)
   table_range.PasteExcelTable(False, False, False)
```

It will keep the formatting from the workbook.