# How can I write the output of an iterative function into separate word fil

Tags: python, pandas, output

```
for i in range(0,len(num_vars)):
    variable_evaluation_3d_plot(df, num_vars[i], "lineasgn_grp", "avgspend1_12", "lineasgn")
```

I want the output of variable_evaluation_3d_plot function to be printed in separate word file for every iteration.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596518/writing-a-python-pandas-dataframe-to-word-document) help? There're answers providing a function for this operation, you can use it on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can do some modification in your code to achieve this.

```
from docx import Document

def create_word_document(content, filename):
    doc = Document()
    doc.add_paragraph(content)
    doc.save(filename)

num_vars = ["var1", "var2", "var3"]

for i in range(len(num_vars)):
    content = variable_evaluation_3d_plot(df, num_vars[i], "lineasgn_grp", "avgspend1_12", "lineasgn")
    filename = f"output_{num_vars[i]}.docx"   
    create_word_document(content, filename)
```

Comment: The word file is being generated but the contents are not printed in it. Do you know how can that be achieved?